# process at top level without reading next line

Tags: awk

Is there a way to start processing at top level again? `next` does this but it also reads a line from input. I want to do it *without* reading another line.

My use-case is that when I see line matching `pattern1` I want to stop processing until I see a line matching `pattern2`. If there was an `ungetline` I would have done

```
/pattern1/ {
   getline;
   while (! /pattern2/ ) { getline; }
   ungetline; }
```

I could be stuck in procedural approach

Comment: there is no rewind function in awk. So you need to rethink your approach. See ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk/html_node/Rewind-Function.html

Comment: It would be good to show us with an actual file and an exact expected output, so that we can see if it can be done in alternate ways

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output otherwise you're likely to get a solution to a different problem than the one you actually have. As written you have stated an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and it's extremely vague what you actually want to do (you're apparently asking to identify "pattern2" without reading lines from the input file - think about that!).

Comment: You could always read the whole file into `NR` indexed array and build the control on it yourself.

Comment: @EdMorton I am afraid I cannot describe the original problem but it is unclear to me why you think I am 'asking to identify "pattern2" without reading lines from the input file'. I do think the example code I gave, albeit with non-existent function ungetline, similar to unget* functions in buffered apis, pretty clearly describes what I want to do.  I will resist giving a made up example, but imagine that I am asking whether there is a more concise way of doing what scheff has written in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43299029/18573)

Comment: @JamesBrown I don't want to read the whole file, but I can do it with buffering 1 line and creating patterns for that buffered line instead of the current line. Thanks, nice idea

Comment: I think that because you said it: `without reading next line...until I see a line matching pattern2`. wrt `I cannot describe the original problem` and `I will resist giving a made up example` - don't resist, just do it if you want to encourage people to read and answer your question. Why do you think you only have 1, tentative, answer so far - is it because we don't know how to use awk or because we don't understand your requirements? See [ask]. What you've posted so far is a classic [XY Problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=xy+problem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: @EdMorton you are mixing up two sentences. The without reading next line is in the context of the `next` command having already read a line. Thanks for the educational pointer or getting responses. I am aware of it, as I am of XY problem. What I do not want to do is create a made-up example. In any case this is not so pressing a problem that I would be stuck without an answer. As a matter of fact, I have already found the answer -- which is that a function such as what I am looking for does not exist.

Comment: I am not mixing up 2 sentences, I'm concatenating 2 statements you made to explain why I "think" you said them. Given you refuse to provide and example for us to be able to help you, it is good that you're happy with not getting a solution to your problem and resigning yourself to thinking the problem is simply unsolvable. Good luck with your continued investigation into how to use awk or otherwise manipulate text.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the encouragement. Been learning awk for 25 years (and still haven't learned much as you can see haha only serious) and hope to be learning for another 25.

Comment: You're welcome. I've also been learning awk for 25 years (spent 10 years before that thrashing with sed+grep+shell+etc.) and it is too bad you weren't willing to provide an example as it sounded like an interesting problem that I was actually looking forward to answering once I understood the exact problem (investing time providing an answer to the wrong problem is immensely frustrating!). Oh well. I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the case you described I would use the folling approach:

```
BEGIN { skip = 0 }

/pattern1/ { skip = 1 ; next }

skip && /pattern2/ { skip = 0 }

!skip && /text/ {
  print "Found text which is not between pattern1 and pattern2"
  next
}

!skip {
  print $0
}
```

The `!skip` enables last two rules only if `skip`is 0.

But this should work also:

```
BEGIN { skip = 0 }

/pattern1/ { skip = 1 ; next }

skip && /pattern2/ { skip = 0 }

skip { next }

/text/ {
  print "Found text which is not between pattern1 and pattern2"
  next
}

{ # else...
  print $0
}
```

Notes:

1. `pattern2` is processed in the above examples. (Place a `next` into its action if this is not desired.)
2. The `BEGIN` rule is actually not necessary but somehow nice to document the special meaning of the `skip` variable.

Comment: Thanks Scheff I am doing something similar but was looking for either a shorter way to do to it or the idiomatic awk way

Comment: @MiserableVariable I'm not sure but I believe this is the "awk way": introducing state in pattern matching. It would be done similar in `lex`/`flex` except that there exist explicit STATEs. More complex solutions could be achieved using one awk script to split input into multiple output channels/files and applying other awk scripts to them (all stitched together with a `bash` script). I prefer solutions where everything is in one script even if it is a little bit more complicated in this case.